# implement a standard header nav in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is more of a "how to approach it" style question. But, if I'm writing in ROR a header and navigation that requires a database query, but is the same on every page. How should I set the variable?

So far I've been repeating the request in each controller, I saw a post mentioning filters. But is it the best way to approach this?

Basically what I"m trying to do is execute this code to generate the categories for a header navigation:

```
 @top_categories = Category.roots
```

Then in the view there's a partial called _header that reads the categories, and this is included in the default layouts.

I'd like that variable to be available to all pages as the header is the same on all pages, but being new to Ruby I"m not sure how to do that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also consider doing a fragment cache as db queries on the home page can be a real drag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a helper (in `application_helper.rb`). You can just call `Category.roots` in the helper method, and you don't need to clutter up your controller with callbacks.

An example..

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def nav_header
    Category.roots.map |category|
      content_tag( :div, category.name, :class => 'category_link' )
    end.join
  end
end
```

Of course while you don't want complex logic in your views in this case the query is simple enough that you could just include it in the partial, you don't **have** to preload everything:

```
<% Category.roots.each |category| -%>
  <%= link_to category.name, category %>
<% end -%>
```

Of course using a before filter is fine too. Neither solution is inherently 'better', but I prefer to keep my controller as clean as possible.

Comment: HI Peter, I'm trying the helper method syntax you have written. How would I invoke that helper in the view, it seems to be outputting escaped html for li tag.module ApplicationHelper
  
  def top_categories
    Catalog::Category.roots.map do |cat|
      content_tag( :li, cat.name)
    end.join
  end
end<%= top_categories %>

Comment: @RichardG You're right, in Rails 3 you have to mark the output as html safe to prevent it being escaped. To do that you can add `.html_safe` after `.join`. Use with care ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a helper method in your applicaion_controller.rb or in application_helper.rb.
You can access methods in application_controller from everywhere (I think ;) ).

If you have static content like an array or something you can store this in application.rb or put it in an extra rb file in the config/initializers folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `before_filte` in `ApplicationController` is the best `DRY` approach in this case.

In this way, before any request to any controller, this method will be fired where you will load the Categories as you have written.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question your Categories are not changed a lot.
You can load all Categories into a global Hash and use it in application.

Put code like this in ApplicationController

```
  before_filter :fill_categories


  def fill_categories
    if $CATEGORIES.blank?
      for category in Category.roots
        $CATEGORIES[category.category_id] = category
      end
    end
  end
```

So You'll have The $CATEGORIES list available thought out your application.